# How to create Rails page that has data containing specific value in a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sqlite

I have a page in my rails app "sp5s#index" that is populated with data. On this page a have a column named Lab. I would like to know how to create another webpage that contains only the data with the specific Lab value of "primary". I have a search field using sunspot solr that allows me to search for it but I want its own page with the required data. After creating this page I would also like to to update whenever I create new entries into "sp5s#index" with the value of "primary" under the lab column. I am new to rails and have been hacking away through different tutorials and learning as I go. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

**Controller**

```
class Sp5sController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_sp5, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /sp5s
  # GET /sp5s.json
  def index
    @search = Sp5.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      order_by(:RU, :desc)
    end    
    @sp5s = @search.results
  end
```

**View**

```
<% provide(:title, "SP5") %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1>SP5</h1>

<%= form_tag sp5s_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<head>
<style>

table, th, td { border: 1px solid black;}

th, td { padding: 15px;}
</style>
</head>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ru</th>
      <th>Devname</th>
      <th>Devtype</th>
      <th>Lab</th>
      <th>Swportib</th>
      <th>Swport1</th>
      <th>Swport2</th>
      <th>Swport3</th>
      <th>Ibip</th>
      <th>Nic1</th>
      <th>Nic2</th>
      <th>Nic3</th>
      <th>Nic1mac</th>
      <th>Nic2mac</th>
      <th>Nic3mac</th>
      <th>Ibmac</th>
      <th>Psu1</th>
      <th>Psu2</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @sp5s.each do |sp5| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= sp5.RU %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.DevName %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.DevType %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.Lab %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.swPortIB %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.swPort1 %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.swPort2 %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.swPort3 %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.IBIP %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.NIC1 %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.NIC2 %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.NIC3 %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.NIC1mac %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.NIC2mac %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.NIC3mac %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.IBmac %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.PSU1 %></td>
        <td><%= sp5.PSU2 %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', sp5 %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_sp5_path(sp5) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', sp5, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Sp5', new_sp5_path %>
```

I want to create a new page with only the data of the items that have the "Lab" column value of "primary".

Comment: Can you post the controller and view code? And pleas point exactly to this values which you want to have on your "Lab" view. It seems, that you just want to have a "show" view, which you easily can get through Rails. But without further and detailed informations this is only guessing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer:

You would create a new view in your controller, and assign the instance variable using arel, this would only pick out the entries that had primary in that column.

```
def primary 
    @sp5s = Sp5.where("lab like ?", "%primary%")
end
```

Then, create a view for that page, eg. `app/views/sp5s/primary.html.erb`

and in that view perform your loop the same as in the view in your example code in your question. This time, because the instance variable is not the search, it is set to the database search where lab == primary, it will now loop only the primary ones.

You may have to set a route to this page, depending on if you are using resources or not.

Eg. `get '/primary/', to: 'sp5s#primary'`

Comment: i have edited my question with my controller and view code. I do not have a resource called "Labs". Lab is a column name in my sp4s and sp5s resources.

Comment: thanks a bunch for your help @abbott567. I implemented it and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to have helped

Comment: how do i format it so It checks for more then one entry. Like "%primary%" and "%secondary%" for instance.

Comment: Use ` where("lab like ? AND lab like ?", "%primary%", "%secondary%")`

Comment: hmm I have tried your suggestion as you showed and in different formats and no luck. Any idea as to why this might be?